# Multiple (per page) vs Single (static/global) Database Connection

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, tcp

I'm working on a Asp.Net website. Currently, I'm creating (and closing) a db connection per page (on load). But I'm not sure, that is the true way. I wonder, if I create a db connection in a static class or WebApplication's main Global.asax, may it be better than creating db connections per page?

*Btw, I'm using MySQL, not MsSQL!*

Comment: Your current approach is right and go with it

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Maybe more detailed answer/comment?

Comment: Read here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17768/ADO-NET-Connection-Pooling-at-a-Glance

Comment: @ZoharPeled So, .Net pools connections automatically! Got it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It is best practise to open a connection and after use to close it. Connetions are pooled and the used connection will be released for re-use to the connection pool. Also connections are not thread safe and you will run into problems using one global connection for a multi threaded application like Asp.Net.